# Can't delete ParseObject

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, stetho

I encountered a strange error. I can't delete my `Favourite` Object which extends `ParseObject`.

The error occurs when I am trying execute this code:

```
ParseQuery<Favourite> query = getCurrentUserFavouriteTracks(user, track);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Favourite>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<Favourite> objects, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            for (Favourite favourite : objects)
                favourite.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e != null)
                            Log.e("DEBUG_TAG", "Error", e);
                    }
                });
        }
    }
});
```

`List<Favourite> objects` is non-null and not empty.
After executing the code above,I recive current error in this line `Log.e("DEBUG_TAG", "Error", e);`:

> com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody$2 cannot be cast to
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient$ParseOkHttpRequestBody

I've found some information that the error might be connected with Stetho.
[Link](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/226)

Here is my `build.gradle` and extended `Application.class`

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
    // Optional -- Hamcrest library
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    // Optional -- UI testing with Espresso
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.3@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parseinterceptors:0.0.1'
}
```

.

```
ParseObject.registerSubclass(Track.class);
ParseObject.registerSubclass(ParseWaypoint.class);
ParseObject.registerSubclass(UserType.class);
ParseObject.registerSubclass(City.class);
ParseObject.registerSubclass(ReachedWaypoint.class);
ParseObject.registerSubclass(TrackWaypoint.class);
ParseObject.registerSubclass(Favourite.class);

ParseUser.registerSubclass(MyParseUser.class);

Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);

    Parse.addParseNetworkInterceptor(new ParseStethoInterceptor());
}

Parse.initialize(this, "****", "****");
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

I hope you will help me. If you have some questions, please comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade Parse Android SDK to 1.13.0, that should fix it. (Note: The issue exists in 1.13.1).